# Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)

Tags: docker, laravel-sail

I have tried changing the APP_URL in env,
Updated Chrome driver.

Tried dusk outside sail shell using "sail dusk" and getting..

Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   (Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.110)

If I try inside sail shell, I'm getting..

Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused.

I couldn't find any answers anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

You can update the chrome version and find the chromewebdriver compatible with it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).